# Sort an Array of MovieClips on values within their child clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class called Table that is linked to a clip on the stage.
During setup I create many Table instances and pass each one an instance of a TableData class. This TableData object includes an ID value.

I put a selection of my Table objects in an `Array` which I would lik eto sort based on the ID value within each Table's instance of TableData.

What I had hoped to use was something like: `myArray.sortOn("tableData.id");`

This doesn't seem to work and I assume that `Array.sortOn()` can't drill down into child clips.
Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: I've managed to get round this by storing a duplicate ID value in my Table class and sorting on that. This works but is not ideal as the ID value will change quite often and I have to extra work to keep the duplicate updated. I'm still interested to hear if there is cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Array` and generic `Vector.<>` collections both provide an alternate form of the `.sort()` method which takes a function. You can provide your own sorting implementation, in this case which peeks objects and compares only specific pieces of them.

Consider the following class:

```
class TableData {
    public var ID:String;

    public function TableData(id:String):void {
        this.ID = id;
    }

}
```

This is a simplified version of your `TableData` class that only provides a `ID`. Then a simplified `Table` class:

```
class Table {

    private var _data:TableData;

    public function get data():TableData {
        return _data;
    }

    public function Table(tableData:TableData) {
        _data = tableData;
    }

}
```

Finally, lets put them to use, and spin up a new collection.

```
var list:Vector.<Table> = new Vector.<Table>();

list.push(new Table(new TableData("X")));
list.push(new Table(new TableData("C")));
list.push(new Table(new TableData("S")));
list.push(new Table(new TableData("A")));
```

Now, we need to make a new function that will actually do our comparison:

```
private function sortUsingDataID(a:Table, b:Table):int {
    var aID:String = a.data.ID;
    var bID:String = b.data.ID;
    return aID < bID ? aID == bID ? 0 : -1 : 1;
}
```

This function will expect to get two items, and should return either `-1`, `0`, or `1`. If `a` should come before `b` then the function should return `-1`. Otherwise, if `a` should come after `b`, then it should return `1`. Lastly, if the two are the same, then it should return a value of `0`.

So, now we just need to tell the array to resort itself using our custom sorting function by calling `.sort` and passing in our function.

```
list.sort(sortUsingDataID);
```

Now the `list` should be sorted the way that you want.

See an [working example here](http://wonderfl.net/c/g7ir).

See the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html) for more details

Comment: Cheers :) Good answer, well explained. Thanks for your help.